# Intuitive auto-population of data between two worksheets

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have two excel tables. One is a list of names with a calendar that tracks number of days traveled and puts it in percentage. The other table shows proposed travel schedules for the same list of people but in a different format. I have to manually find their percentage in table 1 and input them to the second table for presentations. I want to develop something that reads the names in both tables and can copy their travel time percentage into the second chart. Maybe adding it in the cell or to a blank row below. I have been unable to find any previous threads relating to this. I am new to programing and do not know if this can be done in VBA macro for excel. Does anyone know what functions I could use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way is to use powerpivot. You'll have to look at your version of excel to see how to access it. For instance, powerpivot is included and preset in excel 2016, and is a free add-on you'll need to download for excel 2010.

You can uplaod both those tables into the powerpivot model, define the relationship between the two tables (as simple as dragging the relationships in a diagram view). Then you literally have a pivot table that connects both and you can create a measure that does what you're saying. The plus is that there's so much more you can do!
Hearing how your data is set up if you run through a powerpivot table tutorial you might even rethink your data set-up. The advantage is you don't need to learn vba just learn to apply your current and new excel skills. A good starting point is here: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg413497(v=sql.110).aspx

There are also 5 min youtube clips that'll give you a good idea of what else you can do with it.